# How to fix "Stripe.setPublishableKey is not a function"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I'm using v2 version of stripe payment and I am tring to fix the issue of `Stripe.setPublishableKey` function.

Rails => `5.2.2` and Ruby => `2.5.5`

Check below steps

- Click on "Payment modal" button (open the modal)

  - In modal there is present some content and "Initial Payment" button
- Click on "Initial Payment" button

  - Here call the partial of payment and there is set the publishable key in JavaScript on-load event
  - Like `Stripe.setPublishableKey('pub_key_xxxxxxxxxxxxx');`
- Suddenly Modal is closed

When I am trying to dubug my code then I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Stripe.setPublishableKey is not a function`

It's working well If i am not declaring this in javascript

Could you help me without using v3 version of stripe?

Comment: You should make sure that Stripe is already loaded before you call `setPublishableKey`, usually by putting the JS call inside a `$(window).on("load", function(){` for example. You should still look at Elements because it saves you the burden of PCI compliance https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance

Comment: @koopajah After added code inside `$(window).on("load", function(){`  modal is closed but issue is that now my javascript is not working. `setPublishableKey` not set the publishable key.

Comment: For testing I have added `console.log` inside `$(window).on("load", function(){` but nothing display in console

Comment: @koopajah still facing same issue. I am using modal so it's not possible to load window. Also tried with on load event but display same error `Uncaught TypeError: Stripe.setPublishableKey is not a function`

Comment: @ParulKanani: Check out this: https://github.com/tansengming/stripe-rails/issues/70

Comment: @Div: Yes checked this. There is follow the v3 version's syntax and I am using v2 version